# How to add boot parameters in arch linux

Tags: kernel, arch-linux, boot

I want to add `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1` as a kernel line [as described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Asus_Ux31#i915) but I'm unsure where/how exactly.

Comment: Although the GNU/Linux distribution may play a role by pushing a "default" bootloader (if it even does), this is not an issue concerning the distribution. What you want is to pass parameters to the kernel (Linux), which is the same piece of software no matter the distribution. What hands boot parameters to the kernel is the bootloader, whatever piece of software actually loads and starts the kernel. Two frequent choices are GNU `grub` and `lilo`. You should inspect which bootloader you have, then find out how to configure it.

Comment: The second line of Karlson's post should work fine and would be my choice, I've used this approach to pass parameters to a kernel module before. His menu.lst approach is for grub, and bdowning's is for grub2. All good.

Answer (score 8):

If you've updated to grub2, edit /etc/default/grub
add i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 to the following line(s) (ensure they are not commented)

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.i915_enable_rc6=1" # for both recovery and normal mode`
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.i915_enable_rc6=1" # for normal mode only`

Then update the grub.cfg file, typically `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Determine your grub version and check the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) for additional details. Many users, myself included, switch to Arch because of their excellent documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this site](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_i915_power&num=1) you should add the line to the `menu.lst` file for `grub` to pick up.

According to the [arch-linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1030190) it can also be done in `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf`